# Какой локатор нужно написать, чтобы получить необходимый элемент?

Tags: angular, test-automation, testng, protractor

Есть список блоков с классом .group-list-item. В каждом из этих блоков есть еще два .title.action. В .title лежит заголовок блока(для каждого .group-list-item он разный), а .action это кнопка. Суть вопроса: как мне добраться до .action конкретного .group-list-item, с .title = "Заголовок2"?
з.ы. пытался подобным образом, но не знаю как учитывать .title.

```
return browser.element(by.css('.group-list-item:last-child')).element(by.css('.action'));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красным обозначен весь блок, желтым блок, где находится span с заголовком, на который ориентироваться, а зеленым как раз обозначен блок, на который необходимо нажать.

Comment: Подсказали на другом форуме
return browser.element(by.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'group-list-item')]//span[@class='title'][contains(text(),'0NewProtractor 0NewAngular')]/../../../div[@class='action']"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
//*[*[@class='title'][text()='Заголовок2']]/*[@class='action']
```

UPD: в соответствии с новым примером:

```
//*[./*[@class='title']//*[@class='title'][text()='Заголовок2']]/*[@class='action']
```

Comment: Я думаю, что ваше решение работает для той структуры, которую я описал в вопросе и спасибо вам за помощь, но ,к сожалению, я оказался не прав. Я обновил вопрос. Если вам не трудно, взгляните еще раз.

Comment: @tttyyyrrrryyy, обновил. Надеюсь, ошибок нет, т.к. за неимением HTML пишу на глаз, по скриншоту. Суть в том, чтобы найти такое, чтоб был непосредственный вложенный эл-нт title, внутри которого потом будет еще один уже с текстом.